# Working with server and Volley GET parameter to display User Details

Tags: php, android-volley

It's been a while since I've posted here.
Right now I'm stuck on this area where I have to GET data from my server using Volley. You see I wanted to display individual data from the server; but when the app is running, an error message "Required parameter 'tag' is missing!" appeared. This error message is written on the php file so I assumed that there must be something wrong with my java activity file.

I would really appreciate any help because I cannot find similar answers for almost a week now. So I'll post the codes that are involved below. And please do correct me if there's a better solution to this! Learning Android development has been really fun and I really hope I'll be able to get through this, not alone surely!

**getUserDetails** to retrieve data from the server? Though I am unsure WHY exactly did the params.put("tag","...") not work here)

```
 public void getUserDetails() {
        // Tag to cancel this request:
        String tag_string_req = "req_user_profile";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, AppConfig.URL_USER_DETAILS,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Get User Details Response: " + response.toString());

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jsonObject.getBoolean("error");
                        if (!error) {
                            // Retrieving user's details from database
                            JSONObject user = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user");
                            String username = user.getString("username");
                            String first_name = user.getString("first_name");
                            String last_name = user.getString("last_name");
                            String email = user.getString("email");
                            String type_of_tradesman = user.getString("type_of_tradesman");

                            sqLiteHandler.getUserDetails(username, email, first_name, last_name,
                                    type_of_tradesman);

                            profileUsername.setText(username);
                        } else {
                            // Error occurred. Getting the error message from index.php
                            String errorMsg = jsonObject.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "User Details Retrieval Error: " + volleyError.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to URL
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "checkuserdetails");

            return params;
        }};

    // Adding request to the RequestQueue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_string_req);
}
```

And in the previous code, you'll notice I've used the **SQLiteHandler's getUserDetails** here. It looks helpful but I don't know if this needs to be here.

```
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(String username, String email, String first_name,
                                              String last_name, String type_of_tradesman) {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// Move to first row
cursor.moveToFirst();
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    user.put("username", cursor.getString(1));
    user.put("first_name", cursor.getString(2));
    user.put("last_name", cursor.getString(3));
    user.put("email", cursor.getString(4));
    user.put("type_of_tradesman", cursor.getString(5));
    user.put("uid", cursor.getString(6));
    user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(7));
}
cursor.close();
db.close();
// return user
Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

return user;
}
```

Lastly the php file that helps to determine the "tag" of the request. However upon running the app, the error Toast (Required parameter 'tag' is missing!) telling me that no tag is found!

```
    } else if ($tag == 'checkuserdetails') {
$user = $db->getUserDetails($username, $email, $first_name, $last_name, $date_of_birth, $type_of_tradesman);
if ($user != false) {
    // User found
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
    $response["user"]["username"] = $user["username"];
    $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
    $response["user"]["first_name"] = $user["first_name"];
    $response["user"]["last_name"] = $user["last_name"];
    $response["user"]["type_of_tradesman"] = $user["type_of_tradesman"];                        
    $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
    $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // Or else if user is not found
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
...
...
...
} else {
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter 'tag' is missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

$db->getUserDetails function below:

```
     /**
 * Retrieve user's details from the database
 */
public function getUserDetails($username, $email, $first_name, $last_name, $date_of_birth, $type_of_tradesman) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // Get user details 
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);      

    $user = array();  
    $user["uid"] = $result["uid"];
    $user["username"] = $result["username"];
        $user["email"] = $result["email"];
        $user["first_name"] = $result["first_name"];
        $user["last_name"] = $result["last_name"];
        $user["type_of_tradesman"] = $result["type_of_tradesman"];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are making GET request you have to pass you request values in url only like this  `AppConfig.URL_USER_DETAILS+"?tag=checkuserdetails";`